# How to write this sql query using Rails 3 activerecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to write this query using Rails 3 activerecord conventions.

```
SELECT s.name, s.id FROM tripoli_schools_development.campus_programs cp 
  JOIN tripoli_schools_development.career_categories cc ON cp.career_category_id = cc.id 
  JOIN tripoli_schools_development.campuses c ON c.id = cp.campus_id 
  JOIN tripoli_schools_development.schools s ON s.id = c.school_id 
 WHERE cp.enabled = true and c.enabled = true and s.enabled = true and cc.id = 2 
 group by s.id order by s.name
```

Here are my models:

```
class CampusProgram < TripoliSchool
  belongs_to :career_category
  belongs_to :campus
end

class CareerCategory < TripoliSchool
  has_many :career_programs
  has_many :campus_programs
end

class Campus < TripoliSchool
  self.table_name = 'campuses'
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :campus_programs
end

class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :campuses, :class_name => "Campus"
  has_many :campus_programs, :through => :campuses
end
```

and the all important

```
class TripoliSchool < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection "tripoli_schools_#{Rails.env}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
CompusProgram.select("shcools.name, shcools.id").joins([:career_categories, {:campuses => :schools}]).where("campus_programs.enabled = true and campuses.enabled = true and schools.enabled = true and career_categories.id = 2 ")
```

I'm not sure but you've got the idea. You can see the doc here : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html.

Comment: I get a syntax error with this. :campuses => {:schools}]).where("campus_programs.

:campuses => {:schools} seems to be where the error is.

Comment: Can you try this : joins(:career_categories).joins(:campuses => {:schools})

Comment: `:campuses => {:schools}` isn't correct, it should be `:campuses => :schools`

Comment: Sorry, it's my error. Try this : joins([:career_categories, {:campuses => :schools}])

Comment: Thanks for your help ... you got me started and here is what is working:

    CampusProgram.select("schools.name, schools.id").joins(:career_category).joins(:campus => :school).where("campus_programs.enabled = true and campuses.enabled = true and schools.enabled = true and career_categories.id = 2").group("schools.id").order("schools.name")

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked thanks to Dougui and anthonyalberto

```
CampusProgram.select("schools.name, schools.id").joins(:career_category).joins(:campus => :school).where("campus_programs.enabled = true and campuses.enabled = true and schools.enabled = true and career_categories.id = 2").group("schools.id").order("schools.name")
```

This also works

```
CampusProgram.select("schools.name, schools.id").joins([:career_category, {:campus => :school}]).where("campus_programs.enabled = true and campuses.enabled = true and schools.enabled = true and career_categories.id = 2").group("schools.id").order("schools.name")
```